# classList on svg rect element not working as I would expect

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm messing up with SVG and I can't figure out why I can't toggle class on rect element. Tested only in Chrome and it does not work correctly. 
Here is the [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/donz1gy5/):

**HTML**

```
<svg>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="48" height="6"></rect>
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
svg {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.rotate {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

**JS**

```
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
svg.onclick = function () {
    this.firstElementChild.classList.toggle('rotate');
};
```

Comment: Your JsFiddle works fine on firefox 38.0.5

Comment: oops I forget to say I tested this only in Chrome.

Comment: Works fine on my chrome too (43.0.2357.130 m)

Comment: if you add this to your css: `svg rect { transform: rotate(0deg)}`, does it work?

Comment: The problem is not the first rotate, its the toggle. It doesn't go back to its initial state, right?

Comment: @JoelAlmeida works like a charm :D Why is this ?

Comment: Yep your are correct and after I added your rule in css it magically works ?

Comment: Maybe extend on what you mean by "it does not work correctly", because it does rotate. If the rotation not what you expect or are you not getting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need to add the base statement of the `rotate` to the element else when you remove the class it still has the property of the rotate due to the way transform in svgs works in **Chrome**.

As noticed by **@RobertLongson** this is only a workaround for **chrome** because it works fine in other browsers.

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');


svg.onclick = function () {
    this.firstElementChild.classList.toggle('rotate');
};
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
svg {
    cursor: pointer;
}
svg rect {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.rotate {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="48" height="6"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Are you saying that this is necessary per the CSS transform specification or are you presenting this answer as a workaround to a Chrome bug?

Comment: I think its necessary due to the way rotate works in SVG's with CHROME. I may be wrong. So yes. Its a workaround. You are right. Thanks

Comment: @RobertLongson edited the answer to say its only a workaround. thanks.